# gcloud preview app run doesn't re-build docker file

Tags: gcloud

Following along in the [managed VMs tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/tutorial/step1), I wanted to run some of the later examples locally. (As I would for development/testing.) When I deploy my project to the cloud it works very happily, but when I run it locally (`gcloud preview app run ./app.yaml`) I get an import error because flask wasn't installed / the docker image wasn't updated.

Is there a way to build and run the container locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the environment variable `GAE_LOCAL_VM_RUNTIME` to `0`:

```
export GAE_LOCAL_VM_RUNTIME=0
gcloud preview app run app.yaml
```

This behavior is described in the Cloud SDK [RELEASE_NOTES](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/RELEASE_NOTES) for version 0.9.71:

> For several months on the Managed VMs team we've been testing a new mode of
>       `dockerless` local development on gcloud that makes developing a module for
>       Python, Java and Go users similar to development of regular App Engine
>       applications. This new mode relaxes the sandbox constraints present in the
>       devappserver for `vm: false` applications, and does not require Docker to be
>       installed.
>
> You can currently opt-into this behavior by setting GAE_LOCAL_VM_RUNTIME=1;
>       In this release of the Cloud SDK, we will be making this behavior the
>       default for Managed VM users who are using gcloud.
>
> You can still opt-out of this behavior by setting: GAE_LOCAL_VM_RUNTIME=0.

Comment: Really seems like this behavior was very prematurely made default—you can't run any of the managed VM examples with the current SDK, and you can't even do `from subprocess import call` in the now default dockerless mode. Release notes do not documentation make.